# Put values from arrays into input value separated by commas

Tags: jquery, arrays, join, input

I have multiple date arrays, I need to put these in input type hidden field value.

```
["5/3/2017"]
["12/3/2017"]
["19/3/2017"]
["26/3/2017"]
["26/2/2017"]
```

I want to make it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="5/3/2017, 12/3/2017, 19/3/2017, 26/3/2017, 26/2/2017">
```

I tried with merge, join() but I managed to get just one value to the input and I think its the last value. Any ideas ?

Here is part of the code where I try to do this:

```
        var dayAll = sundayData['date'];
        var monthAll = sundayData['month'];
        var yearAll = sundayData['year'];

        var sundayDatesAll = dayAll + '/' + (monthAll + 1) + '/' + yearAll;

        var sundayDate = [];

        sundayDate.push(sundayDatesAll);

        $('input').val(sundayDate);
```

I get the arrays from sundayDate

Comment: put all the date in one array and then try `.join()`

Comment: That's the main trouble actually, how can i merge the dates in one array. Because i get the dates separately from date, month, year and creating a date string in the right format, than I push the date format into an arrays. I need them in one array. That's the main problem...

Comment: please add your that code here...

Comment: I updated my question with additional code

Comment: You have write this JS code inside loop ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

Note : Replace the code of portions according to your requirement

```js
var dateArray = [];

var dayAll = "5,12,19,26,26";
var monthAll = "3,3,3,3,2";
var yearAll = "2017,2017,2017,2017,2017";

var dayArray = dayAll.split(",");
var monthArray = monthAll.split(",");
var yearArray = yearAll.split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < dayArray.length; i++) {

    var sundayDate = dayArray[i] + '/' + monthArray[i] + '/' + yearArray[i];
    dateArray.push(sundayDate);
}

var dateString = dateArray.join();
console.log(dateString);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: OK, give a few to test this out, makes sense :D

Comment: This partially work, I think the problem is that i get the data from 5 selected days from calendar plugin. For example var dayAll holds data for 5 days - 26, 5, 12, 20, 25 - hmm maybe I will edit my question again to be more clear. Maybe I can try with iterate...

Comment: @Novakinify I have update my answer as per your comment. Now please try and reply me if still any problem arrive.

Answer (score 0):

please check need to give full code for us so know what happened.
but try with this same i thinks issue solve by this.

```
sundayDatesAll[0] = ["5/3/2017"]; 
sundayDatesAll[1] = ["12/3/2017"]; 
sundayDatesAll[2] = ["19/3/2017"]; 
sundayDatesAll[3] = ["26/3/2017"]; 

sundayDate.push(sundayDatesAll);

var manvar = sundayDate.join();

alert(manvar);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/manish1226/8py4o6uc/3/